# cannot package new logo for salesforce manage package

Tags: salesforce, force.com

There is a situation while releasing a new a version to my app on salesforce. I am currently running V1.0 on app exchange and now about to release V2.0 on of the changes I've made here is changed the logo of my app.
Now people using V1.0 and upgrading to 2.0 are not able to get the Image(Logo) however new installation works charm..
Any solution to this ??

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding a new logo by a different name and setting that in your app.  In fact I think that would be the cleanest solution as it sounds like Salesforce is caching the link to the old logo for some reason in those upgraded orgs.